# Is webstart broken in Java 1.7?

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Web Start broken since JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623837/java-web-start-broken-since-jdk-1-7)

My company has an application that launches via webstart from our home page.  The app has worked flawlessly for years and now all of the sudden fails to load when our users upgrade from Java 1.6 to 1.7.  It appears that 1.7 has a bug which prevents it from downloading the .jar files so it eventually times out and fails.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: We use Windows 7 + java 1.7 + webstart in a configuration similar to your description and it works fine. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Check your client to make sure they have a Java 7 JRE to run your app.

Comment: Unable to duplicate here.  I'm a heavy user of JNLP/Web Start and it works fine on 7.

Comment: You may need to look into 32/64 bit mixup compatibility problems.

Comment: Can anyone run the following link in a Win 7, Java 1.7 32 bit environment and tell me if it launches?  Java 1.6 must not be installed or must be disabled.  The link is:

Comment: And the link is http://www.gvsi.com/marketview/app_beta.jnlp

Comment: Be sure to validate the launch files using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  Invalid JNLPs can cause problems that only show up in a different JRE.

Comment: @user1428608 I get the login page (win 7 java 1.7 x 64).